# Criterion to include empty and non-empty values in SUMIFS

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**TL;DR:**

I'm looking to change the formula

```
=SUMIFS(sumRange, criteriaRange1, criterium1, criteriaRange2, criterium2),
```

so that it disregards criterium2 if a certain condition is met. Let's say there is a cell (the "control cell") that has the value FALSE when criterium2 must be disregarded, and TRUE when it must apply.

I'm looking to change the formula to something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(sumRange, criteriaRange1, criterium1, criteriaRange2, IF(controlCell = FALSE, X, criterium2))
=SUMIFS(sumRange, criteriaRange1, criterium1, IF(controlCell = FALSE, Y, criteriaRange2), criterium2)
=SUMIFS(sumRange, criteriaRange1, criterium1, IF(controlCell = FALSE, Y, criteriaRange2), IF(controlCell = FALSE, X, criterium2))
```

and would like to know what value or string literal to use for `X`, or what literal to use for `Y`, in order to achieve this.

My current favorite solution is: (1) add a column to the table, fill it with `=TRUE`, then (2) reference this column for `Y`, and use `TRUE` for `X`. This works, but has the disadvantage that I need to add a column (and I'd rather not mess with the input data)

---

**Long read:**

I have a large table, and I want to calculate the sum of a certain column. I only want to include rows that meet certain criteria - a classic case for `SUMIFS`.

Let's say this is the table, called `inv`:

[image]

If I want to know how many red grapes I have, regardless of size, I can do

```
=SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];"Grapes";inv[col];"red")
```

and get the correct answer, `10`.

So far, so good.

Now, I want to know how many apples I have, regardless of size *and color*.

Normally, this would be easy enough, with

```
=SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];"Apple")
```

giving the correct answer `28`.

However, due to a restriction I have, *I have to include the `col`-column in my formula*. If you want to know why, I'll add it below, but for the solution to my problem, it's irrelevant. What I need to know is, what I can put for the criterion on this column, so that it takes rows with any (or no) value in this column. (Note that not all apple rows have a value set for the color).

What I have tried:

```
=SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];"Apple";inv[col];"")
=SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];"Apple";inv[col];"*")
=SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];"Apple";inv[col];"<>")
```

The first, using `""` as the criterion, gives me the incorrect answer `12`, as it only takes the rows without a color. And the others, using `"*"` and `"<>"` as the criterion, give me the incorrect answer `16`, as they only take the rows that *have* a color.

Does anyone have an idea, what I could use for the criterion, so that it includes both empty and non-empty rows?

---

Remarks for the interested:

Ok, why do I need to use the `SUMIFS` formula this way, meaning, with the `inv[col]` columns as a criteria range?

- Well, first of all, in reality, my table is much longer than this, and I need to do many `SUMIFS`. Therefore, there is an additional "summary" table, which for the example here would be

[image]

The empty value in the color column on the last row means, that the color should be ignored as a criterion. As you can see, with the formula I'm currently using (mentioned further below), I get an incorrect value in that row, because I want to get `28`.

- Because the summary table is also long, the formula I enter in the last column needs to be uniform, i.e., the same for every row in this summary table.
- What seems logical in this small example is something like

`=IF([@color]="";SUMIFS( inv[Qty];inv[prd];[@product]);SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];[@product];inv[col];[@color]))`.

However, this is also not an option in my real-life case, because the inventory table is also quite wide. I have a great many columns that are in the same situation as the color column in this example. (And every additional column doubles the number of cases that the formula needs to have its custom `SUMIFS` formula for.)

- Just to show you what I currently have:

`=SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];[@product];inv[col];IF([@color]="";"*";[@color]))`

which isn't working because it only takes the non-empty rows, as shown above. I'd like a variation on this formula, and for this, all I need to know, is what to replace `"*"` by in order to make all rows fit the criterion.

Comment: Great question. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603022/sumifs-wildcard-skips-blank-cells

Comment: Would a custom function using VBA be acceptable for you?

Comment: @AlexM, many thanks for that. It's a very close case and it almost solves mine as well. Unfortunately, using `{"*";"<>*"}` for "or", and then enclosing the whole thing in an additional `SUM`, as suggested in that post, doesn't work when the criterium has a nested `IF`. This works in ignoring color criterium: `=SUM(SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];[@product];inv[col];{"*";"<>*"}))`. This doesn't: `=SUM(SUMIFS(inv[Qty];inv[prd];[@product];inv[col];IF([@color]="";{"*";"<>*"};[@color])))`

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thanks for offering. I could write a VBA snippet, but I'd really like to avoid VBA if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e), it's still more complex than `SUMIFS`, but I feel it's an improvement:

`=SUMPRODUCT(inv[qty]*(inv[prd]=F2)*IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(G2,"#"&inv[col]&"#")),0,1))`

It is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after typing it.

[image]

notes:

- By default search for colour is looking for all entries containing criteria (e.g. "yellow" criteria will match "yellow-red" too)
- looking for exact term can be done by using `#` around the term (e.g. `#yellow#`)
- empty criteria will match everything, use `##` to search only for empty values

of course formula can be fine tuned.

Answer (score -1):

One way to go about it may be with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Qty],--(Table1[prd]="Apple"),((--(Table1[col]=""))+(--(Table1[col]<>""))))
```

Where we add all instances of `[col]` that are equal to `""` and all those that are not, thus counting all apples, regardless of colour

Answer (score -1):

**Below shown method will get SUM for both, Fruits which has Color shown in Table and which are colorless.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Table Range is `A1:C12`.
- Summary Data Range is `A15:B20`.
- Enter this Formula in Cell `C15` & fill down to 
  get the **SUM**, using **TABLE's parameters**.

  ```
  =IF(B15="", SUMIFS(FruitTAB[Qty],FruitTAB[Fruit Name],A15,FruitTAB[Color],""),SUMIFS(FruitTAB[Qty],FruitTAB[Fruit Name],A15,FruitTAB[Color],B15))
  ```

---

**You may use this formula to get `SUM` in Cell `D15` & fill down, if your Data is `not a TABLE`:**

```
=IF(B15="", SUMIFS($C$2:$C$12,$A$2:$A$12,A15,$B$2:$B$12,""),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$12,$A$2:$A$12,A15,$B$2:$B$12,B15))
```

---

**N.B.**

- **FruitTAB**, is Table Name.
- *For the benefit of the community, I've 
  suggested Formula for Non-Table Range in 
  `D15`.*, you and readers may skip it.
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.*

Comment: I've had the same suggestion, however it doesn't work for the OP's situation. (See comment for my answer, I've undeleted it so you can check).

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thanks for the observation, may be but some technical reasons, while posting my Answer there was only one by **cybernatic** !! And I've used the shown table's pattern (OP's) to solve the issue and it's working for both empty & no- empty ! I think let the OP react on my post .

Comment: Thanks for answering. @MátéJuhász is right, this solution is not practical in my situation for reasons i mentioned in the third bullet point in my question.

Comment: @ElRudi, you mean to say that other than SUM Empty & No-Empty you want to SUM something different ,, If yes then what you are trying to show through Summary ??

Comment: No. If, in your example, B15 is empty, I want to sum over all empty & non-empty values. And I want to do so, by either changing the criterium range or changing the criterium itself (with `IF`). Not by removing the criterium range & criterium from the formula alltogether.

So, I want a formula of the sort `=SUMIFS(sumRange, criteriaRange1, criterium1, criteriaRange2, criterium2, criteriaRange3, IF(B15="", "X", B15))`, or `=SUMIFS(sumRange, criteriaRange1, criterium1, criteriaRange2, criterium2, IF(B15="", Y, criteriaRange3), B15)` and would like to know, what X or Y should be

Comment: @ElRudi,, in my example `B15` is not empty, has criteria `RED` and the Formula you have shown above achieves nothing !!